# How to generate a path/url from a Route in the Routes table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, webforms

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application, and I've registered a number of routes in my Global.asax.

I would like to know how I can programmatically build (generate a string url) any one of those registered routes from within my Controller.

I did the same thing in Web Forms with .NET 4.0 using `Page.GetRouteUrl(routeName, routeParams)` but can't figure out how to do the same thing in MVC (I'm an MVC newbie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx) class inside your controller action.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string address = Url.RouteUrl(new { 
        action = "foo", controller = "bar", id = "123" 
    });
    // TODO: do something with the url

    return View();
}
```