# How to generate a path/url from a Route within a Model class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is similar to the SO question here..

[How to generate a path/url from a Route in the Routes table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278225/how-to-generate-a-path-url-from-a-route-in-the-routes-table)

..only this time I'd like to be able to build a url within one of my Model (partial) classes.

I'm defining a new property that will contain the text to be rendered within an rss feed, and want to insert urls (within anchor tags) in this text.

I found the `UrlHelper.GenerateUrl` method, but get unstuck once I get beyond passing in the appropriate RouteName, ActionName and ControllerName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating urls in the model is actually a bad idea. I would recommend you generating the url in the controller and pass it to the model as parameter if necessary or use a HTML helper in the view which will do the job.