# Turn Action and Model into URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller and action method set up the receive an object and display a table based on that model. Now I want to create a PDF based on the view. The way we create PDF's is to pass it a url and it builds an image from that.

So to get my table view I would call something like

```
  return View("HoldingFeeSearchPrint", _model);
```

but the code for my PDF dll uses something like this that takes a string URI:

```
  // the Doc is an Object that will turn into PDF
  theDoc.AddImageUrl(reportUrl); // this takes a string url
```

is there someway that I can turn the first line, where I am directly passing a model into a string version of my model?

Note the model is an `IEnumerable` of a pretty big object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could interpret your question in one of two ways.

**Option 1:** Are you trying to build a URL with query parameters filled in by model values, and having the PDF builder fetch the content at that URL as a separate HTTP request? In that case you don't want to use a view in the first place, just a custom URL builder method (you could probably [reuse your existing routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278225/how-to-generate-a-path-url-from-a-route-in-the-routes-table)). I don't *think* this is what you're doing, but it's not quite clear.

**Option 2:** Are you trying to pass the PDF builder a URL-encoded copy of the HTML rendered by the view? Assuming this is the case, techniques for getting a string rendering of a model-bound view are discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string). And URL-encoding an HTML string is discussed [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.encode(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: my case is the first one

Comment: what I did was var myModel = Request.Model to turn the model into querystring parameters, then built a url then used that

Comment: The link in your second option will really help improve the way I did it originally